# Can the British slang term "innit" be used as a stand-alone response to indicate agreement?

Tags: questions, british-english, slang

This question is primarily for Brits, although anyone knowledgeable is welcome to contribute.

Recently I conducted an activity at my school to spread a bit of information about common British slang.  I selected the words to be used from a list found at: [88 very British phrases that will confuse anybody who didn't grow up in the UK](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/british-phrases-english-language-sayings-britain-england-uk-different-a8138046.html)

However, it was pointed out that my description may not have been accurate.  I used it as an affirmative answer to a question:

> Boy: Lovely weather today.
>
> Girl: Innit?  (Meaning: "Yes, it is.")

My co-worker informed me that the term most commonly is used as a question tag expecting a positive answer.

> Boy: Lovely weather today, innit?
>
> Girl: Right you are!

So, the question is: Can "innit" be used as a response to someone's statement with which you can agree, and are there any other usage notes that would be important to have?

Comment: The Americanese translation is *amirite*.

Answer (score 5):

As a Brit I don't agree with David that it is ever used as an answer.

**innit** is a monosyllabic teenage phrase, where every extra sound is terrible.

Your second example is wrong, somebody who was saying innit would never say "lovely weather", and "right you are" is very old fashioned, so I have corrected your example

> Boy: Hot innit?
>
> Grandad in a Yorkshire accent: Right you are!

and your first example, the misspelling is on purpose to give a hint of accent

> Mum: Lovely weather today.
>
> Girl: whateva

[image]

Comment: To expand, *"innit"* doesn't really have to make sense. It can be appended to pretty much any sentence, innit.

Comment: It’s short for “isn’t it” but can be used in more flexible ways.

Comment: innit is a stand in for English tags: isn't it, doesn't it, hasn't it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

innit is not slang. It's a dialectal tag in some varieties of British English.

**It is a stand in for tags like this:**
He likes me, **doesn't he**? He likes me, **innit?**

They're nice people, **aren't they?** They're nice people, **innit?**

They left early, **didn't they?** They left early, **innit?**

etc. etc. etc.

Listen to the male character in this Catherine Tate skit:

[innit_male character](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFWkJuPhApc)

More innit: A Party Invite

[innit and I ain't bothered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPZ3bNdl6y4)

Comment: @the-baby-is-you You won't get far around here writing things like this:  Uhh your mum is good at life and is a good person and stuff,

Answer (score 1):

As a US resident who reads a good deal of British writing, I think that "innit?" is short for "isn't it?" and can be used in any sense that "isn't it?" can be. I think that both the questioning sense and the affirmation sense you mention are valid. I write subject to correction by actual speakers of BrE.